# regex expression to search for whole word and escape brackets in the search string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to Regex and need help.

I'd like to enhance the suggested function to search for the whole word.

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');  // $& means the whole matched string
}

function replaceSubstring(fullString, substring, replaceString) {
  let escapedSubstring = escapeRegExp(substring);
  let regex = new RegExp(escapedSubstring, "g");

  return fullString.replace(regex, function(match) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
      return match;  // Return the original match without replacing
    } else {
      return replaceString;  // Return the replaceString
    }
  });
}
```

The above function works if the the substring is "hello (hi)" and replaces text in main string "this message is hello (hi)". Result="this message is bye".

... but it also replaces the substring in the main string if it is "this message is hhhello (hi)". Result="this message is hbye"

Tried:

let regex = new RegExp('\b'+escapedSubstring+'\b', "g");

but not the desired result